# pathlib get base path, given the absolute and relative paths

Tags: python, relative-path, absolute-path, pathlib

I have:

- `A = Path('/a/b/.../m/n/.../z.txt')`
- `B = Path('n/.../z.txt')`

I want:

- `C = Path('/a/b/.../m')`

We have well defined, reliable functions for two of the three relationships between these paths:

- `B == A.relative_to(C)`
- `A == C / B`
- `C == A.unknown_operator(B)`

Is there a clean, exact way to compute `C` given `A` and `B`? Or: What's the third, missing operation? Or must I resort to string manipulation?

Answer (score 2):

What about path as string manipulation using `str.removesuffix` (since py3.9)

```
A = Path('/a/b/.../m/n/.../z.txt')
B = Path('n/.../z.txt')
C = Path(A.as_posix().removesuffix(B.as_posix()))
print(C)  # /a/b/.../m
```

Or remove part from the end of `A` until `A == C/B`

```
C = Path(A.as_posix())
while C != Path("/") and not B == A.relative_to(C):
    C = C.parent
```

Comment: Those are both better than what I thought of. Can you think of a name for this operation?

Comment: @bukzor a name what for ? "find_prefix"

Comment: When B is not a suffix of A, your second version will go into infinite loop.

Comment: Now with the fix it is no longer going into the infinite loop, just quietly gives incorrect answer.

Comment: One could check ahead of time whether `B` is under `A` with `A in B.parents`. Or to check specifically if `B` is a relative path starting at `A`, check `B.is_relative_to(A)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parents` field of `pathlib.Path`:

```
C = (A.parents[len(B.parents)-1]
       if 1 <= len(B.parents) <= len(A.parents) else None)
if C is None or A != C.joinpath(B):
    # B is not a suffix of A, proceed accordingly
```

Comment: When B is not a suffix of A, this will quietly give a nonsense answer. That's not ideal.

Comment: Indeed, it's not ideal in that sense - so one can check it with something like `result.joinpath(B) == A` afterwards.